# Will my OS be formatted if I partition my home directory in recovery mode?

Tags: partitioning

Will my OS be formatted if I partition my home directory in recovery mode? The question is for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumming the root partition (/ partition) is installed on a separate  partition, the answer is no, you should be fine to go! Just to make sure take a look at the fstab file with the command: `cat /etc/fstab` just to give you a example you should look for something like:

```
 /dev/sda1 /
/dev/sda2 /home
```

or

```
UUID=a /

UUID=b /home
```

where a is not equal to b.